Testing the page order of a document created with PDFBox
I'm working on a kotlin application that needs to process a collection of PDFs and merge them into a single document. One of the features the users have requested is to have the pages within the merged document sorted based on the file names of the original documents.
The problem I am struggling with is how to write a unit test to verify that the pages of the merged document are in the correct order. I need some way to extract a unique identifier for each page of the merged document that I can compare against a list of expected results. Does anyone know of a good way of doing this?
For reference, my function to merge a collection of files looks like this:
internal fun List<File>.mergePdfsToOne(
        path: String,
        newFileTitle: String,
        parentZipFileModifiedDate: Date,
        dp: INT202DependencyProvider
    ): File {
        return this.let { filesToMerge ->
            COSStream().use { cosStream ->
                ByteArrayOutputStream().use { mergedPdfOutputStream ->
                    val pdfMergeUtil = PDFMergerUtility()
                    pdfMergeUtil.destinationStream = mergedPdfOutputStream
                    generateDocInfo(
                        cosStream,
                        newFileTitle,
                        parentZipFileModifiedDate,
                        dp.integrationId.value()
                    ).let { docInfo ->
                        // PDF and XMP properties must be identical, otherwise document is not PDF/A compliant
                        pdfMergeUtil.destinationDocumentInformation = docInfo.first
                        pdfMergeUtil.destinationMetadata = docInfo.second
                    }

                    pdfMergeUtil.addSources(filesToMerge.map { it.inputStream() })
                    pdfMergeUtil.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())

                    File("$path/$newFileTitle").let { fileToWrite ->
                        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileToWrite, mergedPdfOutputStream.toByteArray())
                        fileToWrite
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


You could write it on the page, visibly or invisibly and extract the text. However that would also appear if somebody does a copy and paste of the text. Another way would be to add something in the page dictionary, page.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.GetPDFName("MYOWNNAME"), "1234567"); although you should make sure that MYOWNNAME isn't identical to something used by PDF itself (and I'm not sure if this is allowed or a good idea at all).

Just like @Tilman proposed, add an identifier entry to each page object of the original PDFs before merging. About his concern "you should make sure that MYOWNNAME isn't identical to something used by PDF itself (and I'm not sure if this is allowed or a good idea at all)" - simply register a name prefix for you here; if you use an identifier name starting with your prefix, you can be sure that you cause no collision.
